# How do I get the path to my user's home directory in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to see the absolute path to my home directory so that my code can pick up those files and process. But I find myself having to `hdfs dfs -ls /` and then explore from there until I come across my user's directory.

Effectively I want an `hdfs dfs -pwd` but of course this does not exist. If I can get a command to list a file on hdfs that shows it's full path, that will also work.

Safe lockdown everyone

Comment: I hope you are majorly referring to hdfs home directory of an user. Have you tried hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.user.home.dir.prefix  https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-quot-home-quot/td-p/151921

Comment: Thanks that's a step closer, it returns /user, however the actual home folder of course includes the username. /user/<username>, I'll have to get that from whoami or something, hoping that that matches the version that's on hdfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
$ hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.user.home.dir.prefix
```

Comment: Great that works! In my case I just need to add my username for my own "root" folder. Credit to @yammanuruarun.